# what is the using of Signals in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm watching a tutorial on youtube, and I have a problem, he using ready functions I don't understand what is the meaning of these functions.
my question is .. can anyone explain the **(Signals, Senders, and receivers)**  and their use?
if you can recommend someone course for Django I will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this isn't too bad, I like their example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-and-use-signals-in-django/

^ Their Example:

- Sender: When User is Created
- Receiver: Create User Profile for newly Created User

Also reading the Docs is always a good idea:
Topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/
Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/
^ All the Events that can be listened to

---

From my understanding **Signals** is just the term to describe both Senders + Receiver &:

- Sender = The Specific Event Triggered
- Receiver = Listens for Event being Triggered + Runs command after